# Limit Ajax mouseover

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to know what's the best way to **limit ajax call / time**.

I'm running the following js function when the user `mouseover` a table row.

```
function load()
{
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "process/ajax.php",
          data: "action=action,
          success: function(msg)
                   {
                        if(msg!='')
                        {
                            displayStuff;
                        }

                   }
    });
}
```

Should I create a timestamp and compare it with the previous one?, How can I do that in a **global** context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a suggestion, why not use the now-famous [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin to prevent the accidental firing of ajax calls on the `mouseover` event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript [Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_obj_date.asp) to store the last update time, and check (against a new call to the Date Object) that upon future mouseovers.